# How we can display parmanent the scroll bar on the list view?

Tags: android, android-widget

How we can display parmanent the scroll bar on the list view and I want to permanent change the background of that row of listview on which row we click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set following attribute on your listview. The scrollbar will be always visible when there are items to scroll. It wont fade out, which is default.

```
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
```

I hope this helps!